# What is the default query in solr

Tags: solr

What is the default query type in solr. for example if i search for white diamond then it returns the docs containing white or diamond or both. it means it is by default OR, now if i wanted to change it AND then where i have to change in the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the schema.xml, look for

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Comment: This is deprecated so you should set the q.op parameter in your request handler configuration in solrconfig.xml instead of using the default operator from schema.xml.